# Mathematical order of operations problem? or something else?

Tags: google-sheets, math, formula

Sample gsheet
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1lRs27-1vcF-8SV8l2lwOHYtEVJewn7iurqm93C-KtcI/edit?usp=sharing

I think this two formula below supposed to give the same result, and it did when calculate separately. But when I composed the formula together with other cells, it gives 2 difference result. Somebody could explain the logic behind please? Thank You!

`=SUM(ARRAYFORMULA($C$5:$C10*$D$5:$D10*$E$5:$E10))-SUM($F$5:$F10)`
`=SUM(ARRAYFORMULA($C$5:$C10*$D$5:$D10*$E$5:$E10-$F$5:$F10))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Logic is simple - for first formula:

```
=H2+I2+J2-SUM(ARRAYFORMULA($C$5:$C10*$D$5:$D10*$E$5:$E10))-SUM($F$5:$F10)
```

replacing ranges with values you get:

```
=79,478.14 - 41,000.00 - 64.16 => 38,413.98
```

for second formula:

```
=H2+I2+J2-SUM(ARRAYFORMULA($C$5:$C10*$D$5:$D10*$E$5:$E10-$F$5:$F10))
```

with values you get:

```
=79,478.14 - 40,935.84 => 38,542.30
```

You should use parentheses to get the same result:

```
=H2+I2+J2-(SUM(ARRAYFORMULA($C$5:$C10*$D$5:$D10*$E$5:$E10))-SUM($F$5:$F10))
```

with values :

```
=79,478.14 - (41,000.00 - 64.16) => 38,542.30
```

Comment: Thank you for point that out :)